# How to cast a System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection?

Tags: wpf, selecteditem

I have a method:

```
private void DeletePuzzle(object param) 
{
}
```

param is a `System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection`, that I got from a WPF `ListView`'s `SelectedItems` property.

Somehow, I can't seem to cast it from an object to anything useful. I can't create a `System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection` because of its protection level, and param won't cast to `IList`, `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`.

How can I iterate through param's items?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to cast `param` to `IEnumerable`? Also, have you tried casting it to `IEnumerable<Object>`? `SelectedItemCollection` inherits from `ObservableCollection<Object>` which means you should have no problem casting it to `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<Object>`, `ICollection`, `ICollection<Object>`, or `IList`, `IList<Object>`.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Right, got it sorted. I kept trying to cast it like

```
IList<PuzzleViewModel> collection = (IList<PuzzleViewModel>)param;
```

Which told me it couldn't convert from SelectedItemCollection to IList...

This is in fact what you need to do.

```
System.Collections.IList items = (System.Collections.IList)param;
var collection = items.Cast<PuzzleViewModel>();
```

Comment: You can also under certain situations, convert directly to what you need. If you want a `List` or  an `Array` you can just do `var collection = items.Cast<PuzzleViewModel>().ToArray()` or `var collection = items.Cast<PuzzleViewModel>().ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

from reflector : -

```
[Category("Appearance"), Bindable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public IList SelectedItems
{
    get
    {
        return base.SelectedItemsImpl;
    }
}
```

Selected Items of ListView is an IList, id like to see the calling method.

Comment: The calling method was from a RelayCommand (Josh Smiths version). The SelectedItemCollection was getting through ok, but one has to cast it to an IList, not an IList<T>, and then cast that.

Answer (score -6):

Check The Type:
`System.Collections.Generic.IList<(Of <(ListViewDataItem>)>)`

Comment: I think that's a Web Forms thing, not WPF.

Comment: That's not even legal C# code never mind does the answer provide any useful insight at all.