# inherit style from default style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling

In my project there is a custom style for text box. It is defined as:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox"/>
```

So it is applied to all text box child controls by default.

I need to create another style that is based on default style. But how do I specify in the BasedOn attribute that my new style should use the default style?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use the type of the control you would like to extend

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
```

Full example:

```
<Style x:Key="NamedStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter property="Opacity" value="0.5" />
</Style>
```

Comment: You needn't set x:Key if you want apply additional changes (opacity in your case) automatically (without style name).

Comment: @honzakuzel1989 that's true indeed. It depends on the use case whether you want the key to be set.

Comment: How about in uwp, where x:Type does not exist?

Comment: Thanks. What if the style is for some inherited control class, like `MyButton : Button`? The `x:Type` would be helpful here, but now, I'm assuming it must be done in the code-behind for the custom class?

Comment: I'm thinking something like this can be used in the ctor: `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Button);` And then the style can be defined per usual. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

@Aphelion has the correct answer. I would like to add that the order in which items are defined in the `ResourceDictionary` matter.

If you override the default style of a slider and you want to base another slider style on that, you must declare the "based on" slider after the override style.

For example, if you do this:

```
<Style x:Key="BlueSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Slider}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>
```

`BlueSlider` will have a blue background with the default (white) foreground.

But if you do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BlueSlider" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Slider}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

`BlueSlider` will have a blue background and a yellow foreground.