# Creating style resource for custom control removes template

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a custom control in WPF, which has a variety of dependency properties that allow visual customization.  For the sake of brevity I won't post the entire control, but it basically is setup like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderColor}">
                        // more stuff here
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The BorderColor property works fine if I set it directly, like this:

```
<ctl:MyControl BorderColor="Brushes.Red">....</ctl:MyControl>
```

But I want to set it application-wide.  The problem I have is if I simply set the style with no key, it does not apply.  Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctl:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Brushes.Red"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This does not do anything to the control.  So I thought I'd just set a key and apply that style, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:type ctl:MyControl}" x:Key="myStyle">....</Style>

<ctl:MyControl Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">.....</ctl:MyControl>
```

But this causes the control to vanish, I'm assuming because it's removing the Template.  What am I doing wrong?  With other framework controls you can just set the properties you want without losing the control template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inherit from the default style you have created.

[inherit style from default style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581475/inherit-style-from-default-style)

Comment: With no key, I still had no change. If I set a key and set the style then I get an static resource exception saying my control type doesn't exist.  I'm wondering, could this be because I defined my control template within the UserControl.Resources of the control I made, rather than a resource dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it's private.  You need to move it out, you can put it in your App.xaml, or typically, if you use the Visual Studio menu item to create your control it will create a Themes/Generic.xaml for you, with an empty template.

Comment: Accepted answer, though if anyone else stumbles upon this please note that this won't work if your control template is defined in the private resources of your control itself.