# Set the Background of all Rectangles in a WPF App C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, scalability

I currently have a set of `Rectangles` throughout my application that I define in `XAML` like so;

```
<Rectangle Fill="LightBlue"/>
```

At the moment I have maybe < 10 `Rectangles` so changing the `Colour` of a `Rectangle` is not too much of an issue.

However, as my App grows, I will no doubt have many, many more `Rectangles` and if it is decided that their colour needs to change, I can see that scalability will be a big issue.

What would be the most efficient way of storing the `Background` of a `Rectangle` so that I could change it in one place to change all of the `Rectangles` in my program?

This would also extend to a style of say a `TextBox`. If I wanted to set one custom style for every `TextBox` throughout the app, what would be a scalable approach to this?

Comment: You can use [style inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11581475/1997232). Then defining a new style with some key based on default one will allow you: 1) create control of that style (with different `Fill` property) 2) create new style based on that (and change something in it, e.g. set `Margin`) 3) change default style (one without key). Changing of either will then automatically change appearance of control using that style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a Style:

Insert it in your `app.xaml` to affect all `Rectangles` in all Windows.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Use the Color ala "Lorentz Vedeler" to make it reusable -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myRectangleBrush" Color="LightBlue" />
    <!-- Apply it in Style -->
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource myRectangleBrush}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

OR

For just all `Rectangles` in the current `Window`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightBlue" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**NOTE:**

Do not specify `x:Key` since then you need to set the `Style` for every `Rectangle` you want to apply it to. `TargetType` will apply it for all `UI-Elements` of that `Type`.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="RectStyle">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightBlue" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource RectStyle}" />
```

Comment: Del'd mine since ya beat me by seconds. +1

Comment: @ChrisW. thx ^^ looks like I am more needy in terms of rep anyways :P

Comment: Eh, it's not about rep, just about helping people... Hilfe ist immer willkommen hier. :)

Comment: So ist bier! ...ach ja, und ich bin nicht Deutsch, sondern nur die Sprache zu lernen. Langsam... :D

Comment: I'll be back through .de in a few months. Wir sind alle gleich, wenn sie trinken lol.

Comment: Won't this solution overwrite any other properties in the default Rectangle style?  In other words, shouldn't you base your new Style on the default Style of Rectangle?  And if so, how would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'd define the color in your application resources in the app.xaml-file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myRectangleBrush" Color="#deadb33f" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource myRectangleBrush}" />
```

The advantage of this is that you could reuse the color for many kinds of controls. If your company has a color profile that you use in your rectangles and also for some lines, then marketing decides to change your company color to a different shade. You could change it for all rectangles and lines at the same time.

Default styles for controls are made by adding a style to application resources with a target type attribute and without a key attribute.

Comment: I would actually combine this answer and FeDe's in the case of making it easier to propagate branding. In that I would use the brush resource inside the style template. This way if something needs changed like the brush name you don't have to do it at every single instance and just at the template level. Just two cents.

Comment: @ChrisW. That is definetly the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the themes of WPF Window dynamically, you can create several `ResourceDictionary` files and place then for e.g. in the folder `Themes`:

*Listing 1. ResourceDictionary file (XAML)*

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
... SAMPLE STYLES
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

then refer to the default theme (e.g. Blue.xaml) in the main Window XAML

*Listing 2. set default theme in Window XAML*

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\Blue.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and dynamically switch between the theme (for e.g. to "Green.xaml) using Window's `Control` event handler (e.g. Button.Click event) in C# code behind module:

*Listing 3. Dynamically set WPF Window Theme ResourceDictionary*

```
/// <summary>
/// Dynamically set WPF Window Theme resource dictionary
/// </summary>
private void SelectGreenTheme()
{
    // prefix to the relative Uri for Theme resources (xaml file)
    string _prefix = String.Concat(typeof(App).Namespace, ";component/");

    // clear all resource dictionaries in this window
    // Note: on app level use: Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    // add resource theme dictionary to this window
    // Note: on app level use: Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add
    (
        new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(String.Concat(_prefix + "Themes\Green.xaml, UriKind.Relative) }
    );
}
```