# Why are listbox items not being unselected if they are not in view, after the listbox itself comes back into view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

This is a weird issue that I found in an MVVM project. I bound the IsSelected property of a ListBoxItem to an IsSelected property in the underlying model. If the collection holding the models bound to the list is too big, when you select a different user control and the focus is taken off of the ListBox; when you select an item in the list it will unselect every item EXCEPT the ones that are off-screen. The following gif shows this issue in a test project I made specifically for this issue;

[image: Issue in Practice]

**MainView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListBox_Selection_Issue.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBox_Selection_Issue.Views"
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:ListBox_Selection_Issue.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vms:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstCollection}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Button Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListBox_Selection_Issue.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CustomClass> _firstCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> FirstCollection
        {
            get { return _firstCollection; }
            set
            {
                _firstCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstCollection");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ObservableCollection<CustomClass> first = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++)
            {
                first.Add(new CustomClass($"{i}"));
            }

            FirstCollection = first;
        }
    }

    public class CustomClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        public CustomClass(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `CustomClass` is a binding source, it seriously should implement `INotifyProeprtyChnaged` too. Don't implement a view model class per control. That's always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how it works. If you understand UI virtualization, you should understand that virtualized containers (in your case `ListBoxItem`) are not part of the visual tree as they are removed as part of the virtualization process.

Because the WPF rendering engine has now far less containers to render, the performance is significantly improved. The effect becomes more relevant the more items the `ItemsControl` holds.
This is why you would never want to disable UI virtualization. This is why your posted solution can be qualified as a bad solution one should avoid.

`ListBox` is a `Selector` control. To allow it to work with *any* data, it must not be aware of the actual data models it renders. That's what the containers are for: anonymous wrappers that allow rendering and interaction logic without having the host to know the wrapped data object.

In your case, when `ListBox.SelectionMode` is set to `SelectionMode.Extended` or `SelectionMode.Multiple`, the `ListBox` will have to unselect all previously selected item in case the selection changes. Since it doesn't care about your data models, it only handles their associated wrappers: it will iterate over all `ListBoxItem` instances to change their state to e.g. unselected.

But the selection state will only be forwarded to the binding source for those `Binding` objects that are actually active (because the binding target is currently realized/visible).
Although all containers, virtualized and realized, will be unselected, the `Binding` of those virtualized containers won't update (because the corresponding container is not active and removed - removing includes clearing their `ListBoxItem.Content` property too).
As a matter of fact, unless container recycling is explicitly enabled by setting `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode` to `VirtualizationMode.Recycling`, virtualized container instances are removed by simply making them eligible for garbage collection. They are just dropped and gone without any further modification e.g., of the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` property and new container instances are created for newly realized items.

Now when you scroll the virtualized items into the view, the `ListBox` will generate the containers and will set the `ListBoxItem.Content` property to the wrapped data item. Since in your case the data model, the `CustomClass`, still holds the previous and now outdated selection state (which is still "selected"), the realized containers will change their state back to selected (via the reactivated data binding).

That's why in your case virtualized items remain selected. And this is because you bind the container's state to your data model *in a multiselect scenario with UI virtualization engaged*.

`ListBox` selection states are meant to be handled via the `Selector.SelectedItem` and `ListBox.SelectedItems` properties or the `Selector.SelectionChanged` event. This is not important in single select mode but essential in multiselect mode.

Since `ListBox.SelectedItems` is a read-only property, you can't set a binding on it (like you would usually do with the `SelectedItem` property).
There are many ways you can get the `SeletedItems` value to your `DataContext`. The most straight forward would be to send it from the `Selector.SelectionChanged` event.

From a design perspective, you should generally never set the `DataContext` of a `UserControl`, or `Control` in general, explicitly. The `DataContext` should be inherited from the parent element that hosts your custom control.
A View-Model-per-View approach is always to avoid. It will make your control very specific to a particular data type. And vice versa, it will make your View Model too specific for a particular element of the View. Additionally, it will introduce other design problems that may even lead to break MVVM.
The `DataContext` must always be set outside the control (from the client context), so that the control doesn't know the concrete `DataContext` class.

The improved solution could look as follows:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>    
    <local:MainView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstCollection}"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCustomClassModels}">
      <local:MainView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </local:MainView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:MainView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainView : UserControl
{
  public IList SelectedItems
  {
    get => (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedItems", 
    typeof(IList), 
    typeof(MainView), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(IList), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

  public IList ItemsSource
  {
    get => (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemsSource", 
    typeof(IList), 
    typeof(MainView), new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
  {
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); 
    set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemTemplate", 
    typeof(DataTemplate), 
    typeof(MainView), new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // You can track particular items...
    IList newSelectedItems = e.AddedItems;
    IList newUnselectedItems = e.RemovedItems;

    // ... or the final result
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    this.SelectedItems = listBox.SelectedItems;
  }
}
```

**MainView.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             SelectionMode="Extended"
             SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"
             ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemsSource}"
             ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemTemplate}" />

    <Button Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> FirstCollection { get; private set; }

  private IList selectedCustomClassModels;
  public IList SelectedCustomClassModels
  {
    get => this.selectedCustomClassModels;
    set
    {
      this.selectedCustomClassModels = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnSelectedCustomClassModelsChanged();
    }
  }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.FirstCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++)
    {
      this.FirstCollection.Add(new CustomClass($"{i}"));
    }

    this.SelectedCustomClassModels = new List<object>();
  }

  private void OnSelectedCustomClassModelsChanged()
  {
    // TODO::Handle selected items
    IEnumerable<CustomClass> selectedItems = this.SelectedCustomClassModels
      .Cast<CustomClass>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Finding the fix to this issue took me longer than I would have expected, so I figured I would share my knowledge.

Add `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` to the ListBox like in the following file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ListBox_Selection_Issue.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBox_Selection_Issue.Views"
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:ListBox_Selection_Issue.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vms:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" SelectionMode="Extended" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstCollection}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Button Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I found out that the issue had to do with "Virtualization" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143208/7576836) (Select Show more comments). Then I started looking into Listbox Virtualization. I lost the tab where I got the answer from. So, I can't credit them. Hopefully, this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Having a view-model `IsSelected` property is not always the best way to go.  The problem is that if you are showing that view-model in more than one view, it is now effectively selected in all of them.  That might not matter for you but had cases in which I was showing the same list of items in multiple collections and wanted different selections.  I found an alternate approach in the form of a Behavior that basically synchronizes the `ListBox.SelectedItems` property with whatever collection you specify, thereby taking `IsSelected` out of the individual view-models.  Works great.

Comment: The nice thing about a Behavior is that you can attach it to any listbox you want and any collection you want and remove it without needing to wrote "special" ListBox derived classes or fill up your view-models/views with the same, duplicated handlers every time you want to do this.